# Java: iterating through one list in order of the objects in other list

Tags: java, list, iteration, listiterator

I have a List of object, `List<Field> fieldList` and a list of String `List<String> fieldNameList`.
Each Field object in the `fieldList` consists of String `filedName` and various properties.

What is the best way to iterate over the `fieldList` and access their properties in the order of the `fieldNameList`?

For example,

`fieldList`: `[name, color, size]`

contains:

> ```
>   [field1, red, 10]
>   [field2, yellow, 8]
>   [filed3, green, 9]
>   [field4, blue, 10]
> ```

And the `fieldNameList` contains:

> ```
>   [field2, field3, field1, field4]
> ```

I want to access the *fieldList* in order of the *fieldNameList*, i.e.
        color = yellow, green, red, blue

One way that I know is to iterate through the `fieldList` first and create a `HashMap<String, Field> nameFieldMap` and then iterate through the `fieldNameList` and access the required field properties by the `fieldNames` in order.

However, this involves 2 iterations and hence the **time taken would be 2n**.

> Is there a better way to do this? Can this be achieved in one
>   iteration?

Comment: You can sort the `fieldlist` according to the `fieldListName`.

Comment: If you just want to access it once, and print it, then your approach seems fine. Note that despite requiring 2 iteration, the algorithm is still `O(n)`.

Comment: Your solution is the best (and most readable) one, IMO. You only have 2 iterations if you transform the field list into a Map every time. Why don't you replace the field list by a Map from the start? A LinkedHashMap looks like the only data structure you need.

Comment: I cannot, because Apache Cayenne gives the resultset in List<Object> format only. So it cannot be converted into a HashMap from the start.

How do I sort fieldlist according to the fieldListName and access the properties in one iteration?

Comment: The sort itself would be O(n * log(n)), and it would even be O(n^2 * log(n)) if every time you need to compare two fields, you have to get the index of their name in a list. Your map-based solution is both easier to implement, and faster (O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

If `fieldNameList` and `fieldList` have the same (or similar) size, you simply cannot get better than 2n; One n for each list. You just have to pay O(n) for each list to inspect the contents... unless there is some interesting characteristic of at least one of the lists.